# ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES: assignment to invalid subscript range

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

Good day,
I am using ohmyzsh with a theme from V1rgul for powerlevel9k, on a new terminal windows I get the following error and am trying to figure out why?

```
/home/jamesb/.zshrc:88: ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES: assignment to invalid subscript range
```

echo  $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

```
/home/jamesb/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

cat .zshrc

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export TERM="xterm-256color"
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/home/jamesb/.oh-my-zsh
# Set name of the theme to load. Optionally, if you set this to "random"
# it'll load a random theme each time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
# See https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"
#Powerlevel9k theme customization block


export DEFAULT_USER="jamesb"
POWERLEVEL9K_MODE="awesome-fontconfig"
POWERLEVEL9K_FOLDER_ICON=""
#POWERLEVEL9K_HOME_SUB_ICON="$(print_icon "HOME_ICON")"
#POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_PATH_SEPARATOR=" $(print_icon "LEFT_SUBSEGMENT_SEPARATOR") "
POWERLEVEL9K_COMMAND_EXECUTION_TIME_THRESHOLD=0
POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_OMIT_FIRST_CHARACTER=true
POWERLEVEL9K_BACKGROUND_JOBS_FOREGROUND='black'
POWERLEVEL9K_BACKGROUND_JOBS_BACKGROUND='178'
POWERLEVEL9K_NVM_BACKGROUND="238"
POWERLEVEL9K_NVM_FOREGROUND="green"
POWERLEVEL9K_CONTEXT_DEFAULT_FOREGROUND="blue"
POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_WRITABLE_FORBIDDEN_FOREGROUND="015"
POWERLEVEL9K_TIME_BACKGROUND='255'
#POWERLEVEL9K_COMMAND_TIME_FOREGROUND='gray'
POWERLEVEL9K_COMMAND_EXECUTION_TIME_BACKGROUND='245'
POWERLEVEL9K_COMMAND_EXECUTION_TIME_FOREGROUND='black'
POWERLEVEL9K_TIME_FORMAT="%D{%H:%M}"
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(root_indicator context dir dir_writable vcs)
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(status background_jobs command_execution_time time)
POWERLEVEL9K_SHOW_CHANGESET=true
HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"
COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"
# /!\ do not use with zsh-autosuggestions
plugins=(k tig gitfast colored-man colorize command-not-found cp dirhistory autojump sudo zsh-syntax-highlighting)
# /!\ zsh-syntax-highlighting and then zsh-autosuggestions must be at the end
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
#Aliases
alias l="ls -alh --color"
# What is Commands
alias whatIsMyKey="echo removed"
alias whatIsMyIP="dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"
alias whatIsAnsiblesKey="echo removed"
# Jump SSH commands
# a few important IP's jump removed as internet...
alias jumpVPN="cd /home/jamesb/Downloads/Software/forticlientsslvpn/64bit/ && ./forticlientsslvpn"
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_HIGHLIGHTERS=(main brackets pattern cursor)
typeset -gA ZH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[cursor]='bold'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[alias]='fg=green,bold'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[suffix-alias]='fg=green,bold'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[builtin]='fg=green,bold'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[function]='fg=green,bold'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[command]='fg=green,bold'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[precommand]='fg=green,bold'
ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[hashed-command]='fg=green,bold'
rule () {
    print -Pn '%F{blue}'
    local columns=$(tput cols)
    for ((i=1; i<=columns; i++)); do
       printf "\u2588"
    done
    print -P '%f'
}
function _my_clear() {
    echo
    rule
    zle clear-screen
}
zle -N _my_clear
bindkey '^l' _my_clear
# Ctrl-O opens zsh at the current location, and on exit, cd into ranger's last location.
ranger-cd() {
    tempfile=$(mktemp)
    ranger --choosedir="$tempfile" "${@:-$(pwd)}" < $TTY
    test -f "$tempfile" &&
    if [ "$(cat -- "$tempfile")" != "$(echo -n `pwd`)" ]; then
    cd -- "$(cat "$tempfile")"
    fi
    rm -f -- "$tempfile"
    # hacky way of transferring over previous command and updating the screen
    VISUAL=true zle edit-command-line
}
zle -N ranger-cd
bindkey '^o' ranger-cd


# Set list of themes to load
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random
# cause zsh load theme from this variable instead of
# looking in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# An empty array have no effect
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )
# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"
# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion. Case
# sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"
# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"
# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13
# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"
# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"
3# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"
# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"
# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"
# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# The optional three formats: "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"
# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder
# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(
  git
)
#source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
# User configuration
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"
# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi
# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
# ssh
# export SSH_KEY_PATH="~/.ssh/rsa_id"
#POWERLINE config
#==========================================================================
#if [ -f `which powerline-daemon` ]; then
#  powerline-daemon -q
#  POWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1
#  POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1
#  . /usr/share/powerline/zsh/powerline.zsh
#fi
#==========================================================================
#POWERLINE - VIM config
# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
```

I have taken out some aliases that will not affect anything and removed personal IP's and links and keys. If you can assist I can provide more information just not sure what else to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo:

```
typeset -gA ZH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES
```

Should be:

```
typeset -gA ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES
```

With the S missing, you're then trying to do an associative array assignment to a normal variable.

Comment: so about that... .. .
Thank you.